# Minimum Redundancy Maximum Relevance (mRMR) with mutual information for feature selection with scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am working on a ML classification project which requires performing mRMR as a step in the pipeline.
I've tried a few ones online, but they do not seem to be compatible with Python 3.7.  I'm wondering if there are any packages that are compatible with the python 3.7 and the current version of scikit-learn?

Below are the packages I've tried:
https://github.com/danielhomola/mifs
https://pypi.org/project/pymrmr/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This pymrmr commit suggests it is compatible with 3.7 now:  [Use newer cython version to support python 3.7](https://github.com/fbrundu/pymrmr/commit/a737859b3f23c3d9fdde794fd4a99b7e5188dfad)